# Change The Default Range of Volume From 0-100% to 0-153% on Xfce

Tags: linux, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, pulse-audio

By manually setting the volume to more than 100% in PulseAudio Volume Control, I will only be able to decrease it by the <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> shortcut key, until it's less than 100% and only then I'll be able to increase it up to 100% by <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>.

The question is, what should I do to be able to scroll past the 100% volume by <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Left/Right</kbd> shortcut keys?

Answer (score 1):

The command `pactl` belongs to the package `pulseaudio-utils` to install it use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-utils
```

Try running these commands (via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or terminal):

Volume to 150%:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%
```

To return the volume to 100% simply:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This would simply do the same job as manually rising the volume level to 150% by PulseAudio Volume Control, and it wont change the default range to 0-150%